# Why is Mypy not giving a typing error when assigning attributes in __init__ that have been type hinted in the class body?

Tags: python, mypy

Here's a sample python file I have

```py
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


p = Person(5, 5)
```

But when I run `mypy test.py` I get the following output

```
$ mypy test.py                     
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Shouldn't it be complaining that it's trying to assign `5` to the `name` variable and I've indicated that should be of type `str`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: Annotate the initialiser, not the fields:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

p = Person(5, 5)  #  Argument 1 to "Person" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
```

See the [mypy Class Basics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/class_basics.html) for this style.

---

There are two issues at play here:

- Entirely unannotated functions/methods are not checked by MyPy:

  > #### MyPy: [Function signatures and dynamic vs static typing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#function-signatures-and-dynamic-vs-static-typing)
  >
  > A function without type annotations is considered to be dynamically typed by mypy:
  >
  > ```py
  > def greeting(name):
  >     return 'Hello ' + name
  > ```
  >
  > By default, mypy will not type check dynamically typed functions. This means that with a few exceptions, mypy will not report any errors with regular unannotated Python.

  If you want to eliminate such issues slipping through, use the flags [`--disallow-untyped-defs`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-disallow-untyped-defs) or [`--check-untyped-defs`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-check-untyped-defs).
- Unannotated parameters default to `Any`:

  ```
  class Person:
      name: str
      age: int

      def __init__(self, name, age: int) -> None:
          self.name = name
          reveal_type(name)       # Revealed type is 'Any'

          reveal_type(self.name)  # Revealed type is 'builtins.str'
          self.age = age
  ```

  Even if your `__init__` is checked, its arguments take and provide the always-compatible `Any` type.

To directly fix both issues, annotate the initialiser arguments instead of the class slots if the two coincide. Only annotate the class slots if `__init__` is generated automatically, e.g. via `dataclasses.dataclass` or `typing.NamedTuple`, or annotate them in addition if inference is not sufficently precise.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`reveal_type`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#displaying-the-type-of-an-expression) gives you a helpful hint why this happens:

```
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        reveal_type(self.name)


p = Person(5, 5)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> test_mypy1.py:8: note: Revealed type is 'Any'
> test_mypy1.py:8: note: 'reveal_type' always outputs 'Any' in unchecked functions
> ```

So the reason is that Mypy doesn't check the `__init__` method for type errors at all by default, since you haven't type annotated it.

Comment: Am I not annotating with the first two lines in the `Person` class?

Comment: No, the `__init__` method itself is left totally unchecked since you didn't add type hints for it. The proper way to type it would be to remove the type hints from the class body and specify the method signature as `def __init__(self, name: str, age: int) -> None:`

Comment: This is not (solely) due to mypy ignoring the function becuase of missing annotations. Running mypy with ``--check-untyped-defs`` will also not trigger an error.