# Mypy doesn't detect awaiting a function call that returns None

Tags: python-asyncio, mypy

Consider the following code:

```py
import asyncio


def a():
    print("whatever")


async def b():
    await a()


asyncio.run(b())
```

It does not run: `TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression`

However it passes mypy (v1.2.0): `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`.

Is there a setting for mypy, or a way to annotate `a()` so that mypy detects this type of errors? I tried to annotate the return type of a with `def a() -> None:`, but it does not help. Am doing something wrong? Is this a known limitation of mypy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Mypy not giving a typing error when assigning attributes in \_\_init\_\_ that have been type hinted in the class body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66295265/why-is-mypy-not-giving-a-typing-error-when-assigning-attributes-in-init-that)

Comment: Not exactly, but I accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this does not cause Mypy to report an error is that you **did not annotate** your functions. Specifically, there is no return type annotation for `a`. Mypy has no choice but to fall back to `Any` as the return type. And `Any` is compatible with, well, **anything**. This includes `await` expressions.

If you run `mypy --strict`, you'll actually get the following output for your code:

```
...:4: error: Function is missing a return type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
...:4: note: Use "-> None" if function does not return a value
...:8: error: Function is missing a return type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
...:8: note: Use "-> None" if function does not return a value
...:9: error: Call to untyped function "a" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
...:12: error: Call to untyped function "b" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
```

And if you modify `b` slightly to reveal the types involved, you'll see what I mean:

```py
...

async def b():
    supposed_awaitable = a()
    reveal_type(supposed_awaitable)
    await supposed_awaitable
```

Mypy will tell you `Revealed type is "Any"` even though you and me know it is `None`.

By contrast, if you just add `-> None` to your `a` function, you will at least get an error:

```py
def a() -> None:
    print("whatever")


async def b():
    await a()  # error: "a" does not return a value  [func-returns-value]
```

While this is not ideal IMO because it is not very precise and to be honest actually **incorrect** since `None` is of course a value, that is still enough to point you to the error you made because if something is `None` (or "not a value" as Mypy calls it here), you obviously cannot use it in an await expression.

As a side note, I appreciate that PyCharm at least tells me `Cannot find reference 'await' in 'None'`, which I find a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, type hinting the return type of `a()` is not enough to get an error. You need to either type hint both `a()` and `b()` or type hint only `a()` and use `--check-untyped-defs`.

Comment: @nicoco May be a difference in Mypy versions (using 1.2.0), but for me (again, in `--strict` mode) annotating the `a` return type is enough to produce the error. I would generally suggest only ever using Mypy in strict mode anyway.

Comment: Oh indeed, `--strict` works too.